# Which contemporary programming language is apt for implementation of algorithms in cryptography?

Tags: cryptanalysis, secret-sharing, complexity

I am a researcher in cryptography. Most of the time I generally do theoretical/Mathematical work only and not doing the implementation part.

I am not able to get the feel about the time complexity of algorithms theoretically. We can get the time complexity of algorithms by doing proper implementation. I want to implement algorithms/schemes to find out the time complexity and other aspects of algorithms practically in terms of plots.

Could you please suggest me **which programming language is apt for implementation of cryptography algorithms**? If it seems like a subjective question, my intention is to know the answer for the question: Which programming language generally used by majority of researchers of cryptography?

Comment: C is traditional. Rust is gaining popularity due to better safety properties, eg BLAKE3 has a reference implementation in Rust.

Comment: I don't think it matters specifically if it is just to get an idea of time complexity. If you want to get a feel about instructions per second or protection against timing attacks then a lower language such as C or Rust is helpful. Assuming asymmetric primitivites (as doing time complexity for symmetric ciphers / hashes is probably boring :) ), Rust at least seems to provide operator overloading for `BigInt` and is a more modern language by any standard.